# using %x to print the hex address contained in a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

i just read this short article http://karwin.blogspot.com/2012/11/c-pointers-explained-really.html which describes pointers really well. The author however says that the addresses are just these hex values, so he prints it with %x, but when i do this not only do i get a warning from the compiler saying i am passing a pointer instead of an unsigned int, but sometimes i get something that doesn't resemble an address at all (like 1C). Can somebody clarify the issue please?

Comment: use %p for pointer

Comment: I went ahead and commented on the post :P

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Actually, pointers could be smaller as well, for a different disastrous effect. Also, it is UB no matter the manner you lie to the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

`%x` expects its corresponding argument to have type `unsigned int`, which is why you get the warning and funky output.  Use `%p` to display pointer values:

```
T *p = some_pointer_value;
...
printf( "p = %p\n", (void *) p );
```

`%p` expects its corresponding argument to have type `void *`.  This is pretty much the only place you should explicitly cast a pointer to `void *` in C.

**Edit**

Just looked at the page.  Be aware, that code sample is *old* (written ca. 1990) and uses K&R-style (pre-1989 standard) function definition syntax and implicit `int` all over the place.  It's using `%x` to display pointer values because the `%p` conversion specifier wasn't added to the language until the 1989 standard.

It should *not* be used as a model of modern C programming practice.

His explanation of pointers is pretty decent, though.

Comment: so %x didn't require an unsigned int then? And if it did, then my question remains: How come he is getting an output of the type 0x... which does look like an address, and i am only getting a small portion of the address if not a completely wrong value.

Comment: @user96454: if the type isn't what the conversion specifier expects, then the behavior is *undefined*; the exact output will vary.

Answer (score 1):

`%x` is used to print a value in hex. While pointers are usually written in hex, there are other considerations for pointers that make `%x` a bad fit, like that `1C` output you saw.

`%p` is meant for pointers, and is probably what you're looking for. It will format the pointer a bit better, since it knows that it's a pointer.

`1C` is a perfectly valid hex output, but it's odd for a pointer, since you expect certain special things to happen when displaying pointers, like having the correct length.

Since `%x` is meant for hex numbers, passing a pointer into it will give you a warning. One reason it gives you the warning is that pointers aren't necessarily the same size as an unsigned int.

Comment: `%x` is used to print an `unsigned int` value in hex; passing anything else causes undefined behavior. Using `%x` with a pointer will not *necessarily* produce a warning, though some compilers (gcc, for example) will try to warn about it when they can. (That's not always possible, since the format string needn't be a string literal.)

Comment: `%p` is not for all pointers, only for pointers of type `void*`. Only data-pointers can be converted to it, unless the implementation guarantees it (a quite common extension even mentioned in the standard).

Answer (score 1):

`%x` expects an `unsigned int`, passing anything else is **UB**.

For printing a data-pointer, there is `%p` which can print void-pointers (type `void*`, the conversion is *not* optional), which will normally print it with hexadecimal notation.

If that's not satisfying you, consider casting the pointer to `uintptr_t` and printing that using the format-specifier-macros `PRIxPTR` or `PRIXPTR` from `<inttypes.h>`, for guaranteed hexadecimal output.
You even get to select the case used.

Comment: To print a pointer value, use `%p` and cast the value to `void*`. `%p` is defined *only* for `void*`. There's no guarantee that other pointer types (apart from `char*` and friends) even have the same size or representation.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Added that conversion is required, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers if manipulated with the intergral formats like %x or %u give undefined results. %p is recommended for pointers.
As far as the warning is concerned, %x expects an unsigned int, and your variable has probably different size or alignment requirement than unsigned int so you are getting the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Values cannot be "hex". Values are just values. Meanwhile, "hex" is a way to *represent* values for human consumption. "Hex" is a notation.

Using `%x` directly on pointers is illegal though, since `%x` format specifier expects an `unsigned int` argument, not a pointer. A pointer can be cast to `unsigned int` type, and the result can be used with `%x` format specifier, but this will not work in general case since `unsigned int` type can easily be too narrow to properly represent the numerical address value.

In other words, forget about `%x`. It is hopelessly useless in that application. The author of your article is doing it very wrongly.

If you really want to print a pointer `p` through its conversion to integral type, the proper way to go would be this

```
printf("%" PRIxPTR "\n", (uintptr_t) p);
```

Note the use of `uintptr_t` type and `PRIxPTR` macro that stands for an implementation-defined format specifier associated with that type.

Other than that you can use a dedicated format specifier `%p`, which prints `void *` pointers and typically uses hex notation for that purpose.

Comment: this makes sense, but my pointer is int *, so the unsigned int type should suffice if we are considering byte size right?

So then, in this particular case, why do i get these different outputs if both %x and %p are supposed output a hex value

Comment: @user96454: I don't see how it has anything to do with the type of your pointer. The fact that your pointer is `int *` makes no difference whatsoever. In a typical implementation *all* pointers are represented in the same way. Which means that `unsigned int` might end up being insufficiently wide to represent pointers, any pointers.

Comment: What difference do you see in the output between `%x` and `%p`? If `%p` gives you longer output, it means that your pointers are indeed too large for `unsigned int`, which is why you get different (truncated) output from `%x`.